# Is private key required on web server during SSL communication?

Tags: ssl

Does private key is required on web server during SSL communication? I've read:

> In SSL, each party calculates the secret key individually using random
>   values known to each side. The parties then send messages encrypted
>   using the secret key

and

> The private key is a randomly generated key for the session and is not
>   stored.

Above quotations relate Oracle Application Server SSL communication, but I think it should concern general SSL communication. Could you explain, what is role of private key (so far I think private key is required on web server during SSL).

Comment: The second quote is incorrect. It should say *'session'* key, not 'private' key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the private key is required during the SSL handshake as it is used to prove that the server is indeed the owner of the Public Key of the deployed certificate.
But the Public/Private key pair are not used for encryption of the application messages. They are used only in the handshake which creates in the process a *shared key* by cryptographic parameters transmitted to the client in order to calculate it and used for the *symmetric* encryption of data after the handshake completes succesfully.

Comment: Technically, the handshake creates the shared key at both ends at about the same time; both client and server provide part of the randomness. (That's how a key negotiation scheme like Diffie-Hellman — used in the guts of SSL — works.)

Comment: Exactly. There is no 'shared key transmitted to client'. This is a major error in the answer.

Comment: @EJP:You are correct.My description was erroneous.I updated answer

Comment: "Yes, the private key is required during the SSL handshake as it is used to prove that the server is indeed the owner of the Public Key of the deployed certificate."  More specifically, from the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_d1rCXNrx0 and the post at https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/ it appears that the server's private key is needed to decrypt the pre-master secret that has been encrypted by the client using the server's public key that it finds in the SSL certificate the server has previously sent to the client.  Is this correct?